# Office 365 SharePoint Online list export

Tags: sharepoint-online, export, sharepoint-list

I understand that there's no way to have anonymous access to SharePoint Online lists like you can with SharePoint 2013, but is there a way to pull the data from the list somehow where I can store in an array for displaying on another website(an internal wallboard)?

I've tried with RSS but again there's no anonymous access!

Comment: You can generate an anonymous link for a file in a document library. You can try exporting that data to excel file and store in a library.

Comment: Hi @Defias Bandit, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: You could leverage the CSOM to replicate this data locally, or perform an authenticated request to refresh Export to Excel data.

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti unfortunately it won't let me "Get a link" for some reason.

Comment: Can you refer this article for steps. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 2):

One possibility could be since you are on the SharePoint online is to, automatically get data from the list to CSV file through MS Flow.  Here are the steps:

1. Schedule a task (for example every day or week)
2. Get all the items from the list
3. Generate a CSV file
4. Save the file to OneDrive or FTP location

[image]